# Java client for REST web service with Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, rest, netbeans, soapui

I am trying to write a Java client for a REST web service, defined this way:

```
@Path("/")
public class Translator {
  public Translator() { }

  @POST
  @Produces("application/json")
  @Path("/translate")
  public String translate(@QueryParam("dir") String dir,  @QueryParam("string")String string, @QueryParam("user")String user, @QueryParam("key")String key){
    return doTranslation(dir, string, user, key);
  }
}
```

I have tried to use the NetBeans option "New Restful Java client", selecting for the REST source the project that contains the webservice.

But it generates a class with one method that does not have parameters:

```
public class NewJerseyClient {
  private WebTarget webTarget;
  private Client client;
  private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8086/TranslatorREST/Translator";

  public NewJerseyClient() {
    client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI);
  }

  public String translate() throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.path("translate").request().post(null, String.class);
  }
}
```

So I don't see a way to pass parameters to the web service.

I can succesfully use this web service from SoapUI, provided that I don't enable the option "Post QueryString", in which case the web service receives "null" for all the parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the parameters with .queryParam() :

```
public class NewJerseyClient {
  private WebTarget webTarget;
  private Client client;
  private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8086/TranslatorREST/Translator";

  public NewJerseyClient() {
    client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI);
  }

  public String translate() throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.path("translate").queryParam("dir", "myDir")
        .queryParam("string", "myString")
        .queryParam("user", "myUser")
        .queryParam("key", "myKey").request().post(null, String.class);
  }
}
```